# Tizen Kernel image with Printk in net/socket.c not booting

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, tizen

I am compiling Tizen Kernel 3.10. At first it compiled successfully. `uImage` generated, device got flashed and device booted successfully. Then I compiled the kernel by keeping a `printk` statement in `net/socket.c` `sendto()` function, the image generated successfully but the device is not booting with this image.

If remove the `printk` in `net/socket.c` then the image is working successfully. Here I want to intercept the send to system call. Can any one help me in solving this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making some trail and errors i solved the problem by adding printk in a if conditional statement like

```
     static __counter =0;
     if(__counter<10)
     {
        printk("some debug statement");
        __counter++; 
     }
```

the if conditional can be replaced by any appropriate condition based on the requirement